# How to get scroll position for RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, scroll-position

I'm working in C#, Windows Forms application, and have a problem getting scroll position for RichTextBox with large amount of text.

I'm using this code:

```
  public class POINT
    {
        public  int x;
        public int y;

        public POINT()
        {
        }

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

`SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, res)`

But, when control contains large amount of text, resulting y offset is incorect because upper 16 bits of Y are always 0.

Is there any way to get scroll position larger than 16 bits?

Comment: Take a look [at this](http://www.techtalkz.com/c-c-sharp/68735-richtextbox-scroll-position.html#post293785)

Comment: Use GetCharIndexFromPosition() instead.  GetLineFromCharIndex() to translate to a line number.

Comment: Thanks for replays.

@HansPassant - I sucedded to get position with GetPositionFromCharIndex. Namely, this function returns position relative to the contol view, so GetPositionFromCharIndex(0) returns exactly scroll position for the control.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was about time to case this into an answer

```
GetPositionFromCharIndex(0)
```

> Retrieves the location within the control at the specified character
>   index

This will get the offset, of the character relative the the control