# AutoScroll when text is added only if the scrollbar was at the bottom - c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a chat form with a few richtextboxes. One of them is for the messages. How can I autoScroll it when text is added to it, only if the scrollbar was at the bottom before the text was added?

I searched about my problem, but I couldn't find a clear answer.

To add the text I am using string concatenation:

```
rtb.Text += string.Format("\n\n{0}: {1}", newMessage, name);
```

Comment: `rtb.AppendText(string.Format("\n\n{0}: {1}", newMessage, name));`

Comment: @LarsTech I will use it, but I still have the scrolling problem (this method doesn't scroll the text box).

Comment: You could always add a `rtb.ScrollToCaret();` if it's not auto-scrolling.

Comment: Or `richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength;`

Comment: @LarsTech I don't want that it will always scroll to textbox. It should scroll it only if the scrollbar was at the bottom before the text was added.

Comment: See [Get current scroll position from rich text box control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10238729/719186)