# How to check a vertical ScrollBar is present in RichTextBox c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am appending text to RichTextBox. When text is more than visible area of richtextbox then automatically Vertical ScrollBar appears.

> I want to check if no scrollbar is present than set Padding to 5. If
> scrollbar appears then padding should be 0

```
private void frmAno_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayingAnomalies();
        ChangeFormSize();
    }
private void DisplayingAnomalies()
    {
        int length;
        string heading;
        switch (_lstNullSheet.Count == 0 ? "zero" :
               _lstNullSheet.Count == 1 ? "one" :
               _lstNullSheet.Count > 1 ? "more" : "floor")
        {
            case "zero":
                break;
            case "one":
                heading = "Empty Sheet";
                rtbDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n[", heading);
                rtbDisplay.AppendText(_lstNullSheet[0] + "] Sheet in Excel has no data.\r\n\n");
                break;
            case "more":
                heading = "Empty Sheets";
                rtbDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0}\r\n",heading);
               
                foreach(var item in _lstNullSheet)
                {
                    rtbDisplay.AppendText("["+item);
                    length = rtbDisplay.Text.Length;
                    if(_lstNullSheet.Last().Equals(item))
                    {
                        rtbDisplay.AppendText("] Sheets in Excel has no data.afsdfaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\r\n\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    rtbDisplay.AppendText("], ");
                    }
                break;
            case "floor":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        _sizeToChange = true;
    }
private void ChangeFormSize()
    {
        if(_sizeToChange)
        {
           this.Height = 200;
        }
//Here i want to check if scrollbar is present in richtextbox or not 
       if(rtbDisplay.Width - rtbDisplay.ClientSize.Width >= 
        SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth)
        {
        }
    }
```

I have added the code for appending text to richtextbox. Then I am comparing the richtextbox width with scrollbar width.

Comment: You can simply check whether `RichTextBox.Width - RichTextBox.ClientSize.Width >= SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`

Comment: BTW, what is the Padding you're referring to? The Left/Right margins maybe? Indentation? Or is it the Form's Padding? What happens when changing the margins also removes the ScrollBar?

Comment: @Jimi i have a panel in which richtextbox is displayed. richtextbox dock property is fill. Now i want to padding of panel when no scrollbar is present.

Comment: @Jimi `RichTextBox.Width - RichTextBox.ClientSize.Width >= SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth` this statement is false everytime. bcz `RichTextBox.Width - RichTextBox.ClientSize.Width` is equal to zero

Comment: `RTB.Width - RTB.ClientSize.Width = 0`  when `RTB.BorderStyle = None`, otherwise `= 4`. Until you add enough text to make the vertical scrollbar appear. After that, `RTB.Width - RTB.ClientSize.Width = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`

Comment: `RTB.BorderStyle = None` . I am calling two methods, first one which is appending all text to RTB. and 2nd method is checking and comparing the width. But it still giving is zero.

Comment: I don't know what you're checking, what's sure is that when the vertical scroll appears, the RTB's ClientSize is reduced by the scrollbar width, that's what it is.

Comment: @Jimi Can i show you my code?

Comment: Well, that's what you really **should** do: add to your question the code you're actually using. You should also specify what is your current layout (you have a Panel container, apparently), so the context is more clear.

Comment: @jimi I have added the code. How to specify current layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Got this from an MSDN forum)

It's quite simple actually. You have to check for `WS_VSCROLL` style bit in the control's window style.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private extern static int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int index);

public static bool VerticalScrollBarVisible(Control ctl) {
  int style = GetWindowLong(ctl.Handle, -16);
  return (style & 0x200000) != 0;
}
```

Now, call the function as follows :

```
var IsScrollBarVisible = VerticalScrollBarVisible(myRichTextBox);
/// Put your logic here
```

**Edit 1**

Another approach might be this: Get the size of the `RichTextBox` before appending and after appending the text, just compare the `ClientSize` value of the textbox and you can determine whether the scrollbar is visible or not, based on the width.

**EDIT 2**

(This edit is inspired by the comments you'll see below)

Put the `WS_SCROLL` check inside the `ClientSizeChanged` event of the textbox, however, wrap it inside an `if` condition, as follows :

```
private void textbox_ClientSizeChanged(...)
{

 if (VerticalScrollBarVisible(myRichTextbox)
 { 

  //Put your logic here, what you want to do if scrollbar is visible
 }
}
```

Comment: Its giving `IsScrollBarVisible` false even the scroll bar is present .

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan When are you calling it ?

Comment: After appending all the text. It gives IsScrollbarVisible false.

Comment: i have got the clientsize before appending text and after appending text. The clientsize is same and scrollbar is appeared.

Comment: Add a button to your form. First, append the text to the textbox and get the `cliensize`. Then, when the UI is loaded, click the button to get the new `clientsize` of the textbox. If you see a difference, then simply remove the button and grab the `clientsize` property in the `TextChanged` event of the textbox.

Comment: I just tested the "check for `WS_VSCOLL` window style" method @Aousafrashid posted and it works fine. I would check how you implemented it in your program.

Comment: @Andy i can guess why he isn't getting the same results as you and me. Because scrollbars are added when the UI is loaded, maybe he's trying to get the `WS_VSCROLL` bit just after he's appending the text to the textbox, but before it is loaded in the UI.

Comment: @Aousafrashid -- I would put 50 bucks on that guess.

Comment: @Andy that's my man! Anyways, @MuhammadRizwan, try out my solution from my comment. Try to get the `clientsize` or `WS_VSCROLL` in the `TextChange` event. Or another solution, yet a bad one is, create a timer/async function and there, grab the `clientSize` or `WS_SCROLL` but make sure to call the function in `Window_Loaded` event and also to put a delay before grabbing the properties.

Comment: @Aousafrashid Every time i append text to textbox the `TextChanged` event called. Can it be called only once?

Comment: Simple. Just add an ‘if’ condition where you keep checking for ‘ws_scroll’ property until it’s true.

Comment: I have shown the code in question. Can you tell where to add this code. I have tried much nothing?

Comment: @Aousafrashid i have added the button. Called this function `VerticalScrollBarVisible` on click. It gives true `IsScrollBarVisible`.

Comment: Read `Edit 2` section of my answer and you'll achieve what you need. Once it works, just mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @Aousafrashid but i dont want to show a button. Then where i have to call this function in the `form_load()`  event?

Comment: Read Edit 2 section of my answer and you'll achieve what you need. Once it works, just mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @Aousafrashid I have read the edit. I am appending text 50 times. Then 50 time `TextChanged` event called.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan, it doesn't matter if you call it 50 times. Just use the `if` condition to see when the scrollbar becomes true. That should fire only once.

Comment: @Aousafrashid scrollbar is visible but the if condition isn't true a single time

Comment: I think scrollbar is visible after loading the form. That's why it is not working.