# How do I check if a horizontal scrollbar is visible in a RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, api, winforms

I would like to know if the horizontal scrollbar in a RichTextBox is visible.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63566592/how-to-check-a-vertical-scrollbar-is-present-in-richtextbox-c), and I converted it to VB.NET like this:

```
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer

Public Function VerticalScrollBarVisible(ByVal ctl As Control) As Boolean
    Dim style As Integer = GetWindowLong(ctl.Handle, GWL_STYLE)
    Return ((style And 2097152) _
                <> 0)
End Function
```

But I need the version for horizontal, not vertical.

Also, I would to use a nice enum value, but I don't understand what the other author meant by "2097152".

Thank you!

Comment: Both values are documented in the Windows API docs on MSDN.  If you look up `GetWindowLong`, you'll find the set of potential longs that can be retrieved, and if you follow the link on window styles, you can find the list of potential styles that might be applied to the window (horizontal scroll appearing in that list).

Comment: See [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles), [GetWindowLongA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlonga), [Type characters (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters?redirectedfrom=MSDN), [Declaring a hex constant in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240587/declaring-a-hex-constant-in-vb-net), [post](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?681009-RESOLVED-I-thought-amp-H-was-shorthand-for-hex)

Comment: @Craig Yeah, sorry, I was referring to 2097152. which I don't find in the list.

Comment: Use the windows calculator in "Programmer" mode. 2097152 = 0x200000 (`WS_VSCROLL: 0x00200000L`). Also see [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)

Comment: @tmighty When I originally commented, the question said 0x200000 which, as I noted, is documented in the list of styles.  The `0x` prefix is C-style, for VB the `&H` prefix is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I was guided to the answer:

```
Private Const WS_VSCROLL As Integer = 2097152
Private Const WS_HSCROLL As Integer = 1048576

Public Function HorizontalScrollBarVisible(ByVal ctl As Control) As Boolean
    Dim style As Integer = GetWindowLong(ctl.Handle, GWL_STYLE)
    Return ((style And WS_HSCROLL) <> 0)
End Function
```

Comment: I would recommend to use hex-style constants for better readability.  Also, you have a typo, you're still checking for a vertical scroll.

Comment: How would I write 0x00200000L in hex in VB6?

Comment: Roughly the same way you'd write it in .NET, swap &H for the 0x and & for the L.  You probably wouldn't want the type character in .NET because of the different default integer width, but the meaning is the same in both.

Comment: [How do I know when the user can scroll a RichTextBox with forced ScrollBars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74017343/7444103)